# Error while requesting products in Uber API

Tags: node.js, uber-api

I am requesting the /v1/products in node.js for getting list of cars available in a particular area but I am getting this :

```
{"fields":{"latitude":"Required","longitude":"Required"},"message":"Invalid request","code":"validation_failed"}
```

Code:

```
var https = require('https');

var data = {
    'latitude': '37',
    'longitude': '-122',
};

data = JSON.stringify(data);

var options = {
    host: "api.uber.com",
    path: "/v1/products",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Token myAppToken",
        "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(data)
    }
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    var responseString = "";

    res.on("data", function(data) {
        responseString += data;
    });
    res.on("end", function() {
        console.log(responseString);
    });
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you post a real latitude and longitude in the format they specified? Update code with actual lat and longitude.

I would start over though using the module that Uber recommends https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber and follow the example closely.

Comment: updated, I am able to get response json by hitting the url in browser